# How to use a linear activation function in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

In CUDA ConvNet, we can specify the neuron activation function to be linear by writing `neuron=linear[a,b]`, such that `f(x) = ax + b`.

How can I achieve the same result in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most basic way to write a linear activation in TensorFlow is using `tf.matmul()` and `tf.add()` (or the `+` operator). Assuming you have a matrix of outputs from the previous layer (let's call it `prev_layer`) with size `batch_size` x `prev_units`, and the size of the linear layer is `linear_units`:

```
prev_layer = …

linear_W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([prev_units, linear_units], …))
linear_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([linear_units]))

linear_layer = tf.matmul(prev_layer, linear_W) + linear_b
```

Comment: are linear_b always  zeros? What is the sense of adding zeros?

Comment: They are a variable that is initially set to zeros, which is usually a good first guess for the biases (absent any other information). As you train the network, this variable will usually be updated to a non-zero value.